# Magento 2 vhost plesk 17 multi store multi website

Tags: magento2, plesk

I am trying to configure the multi site of magento 2.1.3

Here is the configuration: Plesk Onyx 17.0.17 (CentOS Linux 7.3.1611 (Core)) Magento 2.1.3

I followed the tutorial:

Magento + base url etc ..

```
Ln -s /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs /var/www/vhosts/store2.com/symlink

Chown -h store2: psacln /var/www/vhosts/store2.com/symlink
```

On plesk: open_basedir on store2.com: `/var/www/vhosts/store2.com/symlink:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs:/tmp` and directory symlink

But I get: AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link not accessible: /var/www/vhosts/store2.com/symlink

```
Lrwxrwxrwx 1 user psacln 40 Feb 7, 18:55 /var/www/vhosts/store2.com/symlink -> /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs
```

user is the user of the store2

An idea ?

Thanks ALL

Comment: Im add <Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs> Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks </Directory> in plesk site add directive This gives nothing

Answer (score 0):

Don't allow user of one subscription access to another subscription (at least it's a security violation). Move everything into one subscription.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your reply,

What will you do for the plesk configuration? So I can with a multi site in SSL

Comment: @FAPM you can create several domains inside single subscription and they will have same FTP user, than you can set separate SSL certificates per domain.